# Rails Session Store + Redis: Can I set TTLS in redis without setting expiration on sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, session-store

Is there a way to add a TTL to sessions stored in Redis by Active Record Session Store without cookies getting an expiration date to match? I don't want my users' cookies stored and my understanding is that if cookies have an expiration, browsers will try to store them on disk. I'm trying to avoid the risk of session re-use if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set `expires_in` in session store configuration (config/initializers/session_store.rb):

```
App::Application.config.session_store :redis_store,
  :servers =>{
    :host => ENV["REDIS_HOST"],
    :port => ENV["REDIS_PORT"],
  },
  :expires_in => 30.minutes
```

Comment: From what I can see in the docs for [redis-rails](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails), that expiration will apply to the redis key and the cookie. I'm specifically trying to expire ONLY the redis key and not have an expiration on the cookie.